# Preventing auto fullWidth with MUI Button?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a styled Button from MUI:

```
export const ButtonStyle = styled((props) => <Button {...props} />)(({ theme }) => ({
    marginTop: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
    width: 'auto',
    borderRadius: 3
}));
```

But when I create a Button like

```
                    <DivStyle>
                        <Typography variant="h5"> Change Your Password </Typography>
                        <ButtonStyle variant="outlined">
                            Update Password
                        </ButtonStyle> 
                    </DivStyle>
```

where `DivStyle` is:

```
export const DivStyle = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    width: '90%',
    minWidth: 300,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        width: '70%'
    },
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingBottom: 0
}));
```

It produces a full width button like:
[image]

From the MUI docs, `fullWidth` is set to false by default. So I'm wondering why the button still takes up the full width of the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Button` is in a `flex column` container, it has `flex-basis: auto` and thus expands to fill the width of its parent, as expected. See illustration:

[image: Flexbox illustration from Mozailla.org]

One solution obviously is to make `DivStyle` a basic `block` element.

Alternatively, you could add a basic `div` around the `Button`. Then, the `div` element will have `flex-basis` instead of the button.